Creating a magnifying lens effect with Ursina in python
I would like to have a magnifying lens effect in Ursina. Basically, I would like a circle which renders what is under the circle with a magnifying effect.
With Unity, the process I once used was:

Create a second camera (specific fov, etc)
Create a game object with a texture
Render the camera captured image on the texture previously created

Perhaps it is not the correct approach with Ursina, since I could not even manage to create a second camera. And I am not sure I could then render its captured image on a texture.
Any idea how I could create such effect?
I did try to play with some few lines to get a camera
# create a new camera that we can use to render the gaze visualization
c = camera
c.parent = curve_renderer
c.position = (0, 0, 0)
c.shader = 'unlit'
zoom = Entity(model='quad', color=color.clear, scale=10, texture = c.texture, name="zoom")

But this simply manipulated the main camera of the scene.
